# using command line from c file

Tags: html, c, command-line-interface, dot

This code is to parse through a verilog file, and when it finds the character 'm', access the command line and run a simple dot program. However I keep getting a weird error where it prints out a bunch of html code.

```
#include "mycode.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){    
        FILE* fPointer;
        fPointer = fopen("test.v","r");
        char singleLine[150];//printing out the verilog file line by line
        //char* cArray[5];
        char chProgramVar[] = "echo 'digraph { c -> b }' | dot -Tsvg ";
        while(!feof(fPointer)){//file end of file, wait till you get an end of file
                fgets(singleLine,150,fPointer);//gets one line
                for(int i=0;i<strlen(singleLine);i++){
                        if (singleLine[i] == 'm'){
                                setenv("ShellVar", chProgramVar, 1) ;  
                                system("echo $ShellVar") ;  
                        }
                }
                puts(singleLine);
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
        return 0;

}
```

this is the output i get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: %3 Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="62pt" height="116pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 62.00 116.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 112)">
<title>%3</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-112 58,-112 58,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- c -->
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>c</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-90" rx="27" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-86.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">c</text>
</g>
<!-- b -->
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>b</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="27" cy="-18" rx="27" ry="18"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="27" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">b</text>
</g>
<!-- c&#45;&gt;b -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>c&#45;&gt;b</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M27,-71.6966C27,-63.9827 27,-54.7125 27,-46.1124"/>
<polygon fill="black" stroke="black" points="30.5001,-46.1043 27,-36.1043 23.5001,-46.1044 30.5001,-46.1043"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: %3 Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="62pt" height="116pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 62.00 116.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 112)">
<title>%3</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-112 58,-112 58,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- c -->
```

there's more, but it was a very long output.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) The loop should be controlled by `while(fgets(singleLine,150,fPointer) != NULL)`.

Comment: Just run `echo 'digraph { c -> b }' | dot -Tsvg` directly on the command line to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

That is the output of the `dot` command which unless otherwise directed outputs to `stdout`.  Perhaps you intended to save the output to a file?

```
char chProgramVar[] = "echo 'digraph { c -> b }' | dot -Tsvg -o output.svg" ;
```

The resulting file output.svg can then be opened in a browser or SVG viewer.  You could of course add code to open the SVG in the code itself using a browser or viewer.

Comment: see my problem is that it doesn't create the output file. It outputs the same weird html text.

Comment: It is not HTML it is XML for the SVG file that you requested with `-Tsvg`. It is hard to understand what you were expecting if not that.